# Input toUpperCase correto no desktop, no mobile com erro de duplicagem

Tags: jquery

O script abaixo transforma todos os caracteres em maiúsculo em um input.

```
<input type='text' name='meuInput'>

<script>
  $("input").bind('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {
      var newKey = e.which - 32;
      e.keyCode = newKey;
      e.charCode = newKey;
    }
    $(this).val(($(this).val()).toUpperCase());
});
</script>
```

No desktop funciona normalmente, porém no mobile ele duplica o texto. Porém no mobile quando:

Digito: E

Sai: EE

Digito: E é

Sai: E éE é

Digito: E é a

Sai E é aE é aE é a

Existe outro modo ou como corrigir isso?

Comment: Você não consegue resolver essa questão com CSS?

Comment: Não sei como fazer em CSS. E se o usuário digitar em minúscula deve transformar em maiúscula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade o seu código transforma os caracteres de apenas um input, mas sim de todos. E você não precisa de um javascript para isso, basta o text-tranform do css.

Segue um exemplo onde todos os inputs do tipo text terão seu conteúdo em letras maiúsculas.

```css
input[type='text']{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='meuInput'>
```